# Form element replaced via Ajax callback doesn't seem to be submitting or the values are not appearing in buildForm

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I'm having a form with a select list and a textbox. On-change of select list will trigger an ajax callback. The callback function will replace the default value of textbox with an updated value. 
But when I try to get the textbox value in `buildForm()` or if I try to submit the form, instead of the updated value the default value (old value which is set) is passed on submit handler. Below is the code -

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\ReplaceCommand;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;


class MyAjaxForm extends ConfigFormBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'my_form';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form['output'] = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#size' => '60',
        '#value' => 'oldvalue',
        '#default_value' => 'oldvalue',
        '#attributes' => [
            'id' => ['edit-output'],
        ],
    ];


    $form['input'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Crust Size'),
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#description' => 'Select the desired pizza crust size.',
        '#options' => [
          'medium' => 'Medium',
          'large' => 'large',
         ],
        '#ajax' => [
            'callback' => [$this, 'seyHello'],
            'event' => 'change',
            'wrapper' => 'edit-output',
            'progress' => [
                'type' => 'throbber',
                'message' => t('Verifying entry...'),
            ],
        ],
    );

    return parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
    dpm($form['output']['#value']);
    //even after the ajax callback return and the textbox is filled with 'newvalue', dpm returns 'oldvalue' still.
  }



  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    parent::submitForm($form, $form_state);

    dpm($form['output']['#value']);
    dpm($form_state->getValue('output'));
    //both returns 'oldvalue'


  }


  public function seyHello(array &$form, FormStateInterface &$form_state) : AjaxResponse {
    $elem = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#size' => '60',
        '#default_value' => 'newvalue',
        '#value' => 'newvalue',
        '#attributes' => [
            'id' => ['edit-output'],
        ],
    ];
    $renderer = \Drupal::service('renderer');
    $response = new AjaxResponse();
    $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand('#edit-output', 
    $renderer->render($elem)));
    $form_state->setRebuild(TRUE);
    return $response;
  }


}
```

I'm not sure why this is happening, it clearly seems to be the case of form values not getting updated after the ajax callback for me. Been debugging this for entire day. Any help/ suggestions would be lovely.
Thanks.

Comment: An AJAX callback is just for setting form state and returning either an element to render or a command to execute. You can’t add new form elements (or change existing ones) in there, that needs to be done in the `buildForm` method. And don’t render things manually!

Comment: You need to apply the same fix as for the module Examples in this issue https://www.drupal.org/project/examples/issues/2774601

Comment: @4k4 I'm not sure what exactly I need to change here. It would be great if you can provide an example code in a very abstract way.Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ajax callback returns the part of $form which is inside of the ajax wrapper:

```
  /**
   * Ajax callback for the color dropdown.
   */
  public function updateColor(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    return $form['color_wrapper'];
  }
```

The wrapper has to be a div container.

Complete code example  https://cgit.drupalcode.org/examples/tree/form_api_example/src/Form/AjaxColorForm.php

Comment: +1 for the example code. Will this be working for  `hook_form_alter()` also as I'm trying to alter an existing backend form.

Comment: Yes, the form alter hook is part of the form building and you can add form elements to return them in an ajax callback.

Comment: Yeah, I concur it works now. One final question, can't I use  `AjaxResponse()` in the callback and return that instead of returning `$form` ? If yes, can you give a brief example of that too. 
Thanks.

Comment: This is not necessary in this example, if you return a form array an ajax response is built automatically.